# 389 DS Architecture for Multiple Sites

Tags: 389-ds

I'm looking to deploy 389 Directory in my environment to replace an existing iPlanet installation.  I would be using it primarily to store user account data for authentication purposes.  I have two physically separate data centers that I would like to share the same directory tree.  My initial thinking is to setup 389 DS as follows:

- A Master/Consumer in DataCenter A
- A Master/Consumer in DataCenter B
- Replication agreement between both masters, to mirror the directory tree in both environments.

Does this sound like a reasonable approach?  Is there a better way to do it? (ie: four masters?)  Is there documentation for best practices when setting up 389 DS in situations such as this?